# Convert Character to date

Tags: r, lubridate, date-conversion

I have looked into some of the earlier answers but non of them solves my problem so here it is.

The data that I'm having is in the this format ( D-M-Y H:M) and this is a character variable.

This is the data set

```
23-03-2019 21:35
23-03-2019 21:36
23-03-2019 21:37
23-03-2019 21:44
23-03-2019 21:44
23-03-2019 21:44
23-03-2019 21:44
```

I have used this code but the results are showing NA's

```
data1 <- as.Date(data$InvoiceDate,  "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

So please someone help me, I have gone through other similar answers to this question also but the results are the same.

Thanks

Comment: Your format is not correctly specified. Compare the specified `"%y/%m/%d %H:%M"` and the `"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"` (like `"23-03-2019 21:35"`) you have represented in your dataset.

Comment: I have done that also, but still showing NA's. The structure of the this Data set is showing that it is a factor with 97785 levels.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the output of running `dput(head(data$InvoiceDate))`? That will allow people to work with a sample of your data in the same format.

Comment: (It seems possible you have either not changed the colons to dashes or the `%y` to `%Y` as thelatemail suggested. When I do that on factors like yours it works for me. You might alternatively try `lubridate::dmy_hm(data$Invoice)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about just overwriting that column as a date column:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data %>% mutate(InvoiceDate = dmy_hm(InvoiceDate)) #dmy_hm() converts to date
#or if you really need a separate vector:
data1 <- dmy_hm(data$InvoiceDate)
```

you can read about `dmy_hm()`and similar functions in the tidyverse's sublibrary `lubridate`. I find it very useful.